# Representing null in an url segment

Tags: url

What's a safe way to represent an empty value in an url? Something like an empty string or `null`.

Additional constraints:

- it should work for the case where all urls **don't** end with a `/`
- it needs to work as an end segment (common case)

The simplest way is to just work around it, but my intention is to hide it behind routines to avoid branching code (the code for null, and the code for when it's not null, and so on).

Comment: Maybe simply without specifying the value of the parameter within the URL? `myurl.com?empty_param=&blank_param=&not_blank_param=foobar`.

Comment: @sp00m sorry meant url's like this myurl.com/empty_param/blank_param/ etc